# Why there are no phase differences between modes in qft

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

As far as I know the free Klein-Gordon equation can be solved with a plane waves ansatz:
$$\phi(x)=\int d^3k \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32E_k}}\left(a_k e^{-ikx}+a^\dagger_ke^{ikx}\right)$$
My question is: Isn't there are more general solution, which includes possible phase differences between the modes, such that the solution may look like this:
$$\phi(x)=\int d^3k \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32E_k}}\left(a_k e^{-i(kx+\theta_1(k))}+a^\dagger_ke^{i(kx+\theta_2(k))}\right)$$

Comment: $a_k,a_k^\dagger$ may have phases. However, the field as a whole must be real.

Comment: Ah ok, yes the second statement that makes sense to me. but how can $a_k$ and $a^\dagger_k$ have phases? Doesn't that mean that in the second equation I wrote $\theta_1(k)=\theta_2(k)$ must hold? Actually there is a mistake in the equation I wrote the theta's should also have an imaginary unit in front of it. I am correcting it now.

Comment: It depends on whether you mean by $\phi$ the first or the second quantized form. In the former case $a_k, a_k^\dagger$ are a pair of complex conjugate numbers. In the latter case they are operators acting on a wave function, which may ahve phase.

Comment: Do this, if you already haven't: analyze the isomorphisms of your oscillator Lie algebra for each *k* (they are independent for differing *k* s). What happens if you absorb a phase into the oscillators? You *are* considering real *φ*  s, likely. If not, ...

Comment: okay, I think I understand now. The phases are just absorbed into the creation and annihilation operators. Thank you for the clarification.